# jQuery .load() equivalent in REACT

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am learning React and trying to migrate a PHP + jQuery Page to React (without jQuery). However, due to the complexity of the page I won't be able to fully migrate all the page at once. Therefore, I need to start migrating a few of the pages in React already while loading some of the old pages just as content.

I would like to have my Navigation, Footer, ... in React already while still using the content of the old page. I thought something like the jQuery `$(".content").load(url + ' .content')` is what I am looking for, but without using jQuery.

In React I built something like this:

```
import  React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function ContentLoader(params){
    const [content, setContent] = React.useState("");

    function load(url) {
        fetch(url).then(res => {
            let html = res.text();
            setContent(html.querySelector(".content")); 
        });
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        load(params.url);
    });

    return(
        <div className="content">
            {content}
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, I am getting a error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): html.querySelector is not a function. (In 'html.querySelector(".content")', 'html.querySelector' is undefined)`

Just for context, the element is integrated into another element like this:

```
 <Route
    path='/stackoverflow'
    element={
        <ContentLoader url='http://myurl.com/stackoverflow' />
    }
 />
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do here, fetch some data based on the URL and render it into the `<div className="conent">` element via the `content` state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that `res.text()` resolves with a plain string, not an HTML document.

You're also going to run into problems trying to insert an HTML fragment into JSX.

The first problem can be solved by using the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) (or `XMLHttpRequest` which has a built-in parser).

For the second, you could use a state variable to hold the [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) of the `.content` element and insert it via [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

```jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const parser = new DOMParser();

const load = async (url, selector) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${url}: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
  }
  const html = await res.text();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
  return doc.querySelector(selector);
};

export default function ContentLoader({ url }) {
  const [content, setContent] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    load(url, ".content")
      .then((el) => {
        setContent({ __html: el?.outerHTML });
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }, [url]);

  return <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={content} />;
}
```

[image: Edit lucid-snyder-byhlhd]

---

You could also use a `ref` element and append the parsed document fragment

```jsx
const contentRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  load(url, ".content")
    .then((content) => {
      // empty out any previous content
      contentRef.current.innerHTML = "";

      contentRef.current.append(content);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}, [url]);

return <div className="content" ref={contentRef}></div>;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Phil, this definitely solved my problem and although I came across those issues you mentioned already, I wasn't able to fix them like you did. However for some reason, my parser has a problem with the `?` inside `setContent({ __html: el?.outerHTML });`, if I remove this it does work. Using your second method however, this is fixed already.

Comment: @TimNikischin that seems odd. [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is well supported these days

Comment: Agree, though, I receive an error message `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (63:19) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`